# IE 8 - Browse dynamic code

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

I am using IE8 (mandatory, can't use another browser) and I have problems to see dynamically generated HTML code.

I need to check, which class is applied to a certain element.

I am emulating IE8 with IE10, but the result is the same. Dynamic code is not possible to see with Dev Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>).

I need something like Firebug.

Thanks!

Comment: You're being shown the source, not the DOM, in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try out [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). Though note that it's not maintained anymore, so there's no guarantee that it's still working correctly in IE8.